# Javascript Cookie not working on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

Ok I have a javascript cookie , and it work on current page of site (www.example.com/about.php), but on the index page of the site (www.example.com), it is not working. It says the cookie is not set.

I wana to display cookie value in another page. Any ideas?

Here is my code:-

in www.example.com/about.php page on click event of button:-

```
var cookievalue="testingCookie";
document.cookie="stateNcity=" + cookievalue;
var a=document.cookie;
alert(a);
```

and in www.example.com:-

```
<div id="abcd">click</div>

$("#abcd").on("click",function()
    {
         var cookie_string = document.cookie;
         if (cookie_string.length !=0)
         {
             alert(cookie_string);
         }
         else
         {
             alert('cookie is not set');
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

As you set a cookie you should specify an expire time and a path. If you don't specify a path the cookie is accessible only by the current page.

See for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

For example:

```
var cookievalue,
    cookieexpire,
    cookiepath,
    date;

cookievalue ="testingCookie";

date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 3600 ); // will last 3600 seconds (1 hour)
cookieexpire = date.toGMTString();

cookiepath = "/"; // accessible from every web page of the domain

document.cookie="stateNcity=" + cookievalue + "; expires=" + cookieexpire + "; path=" + cookiepath;
```

---

It is quite obviuos then but as the user navigates to www.example.com the cookie will result as set only if he/she has first visited www.example.com/about.php and triggered the click.

---

Cookie management in pure JavaScript is not trivial.

As you tagged your question with `jquery` I suggest using it for cookie management, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458728/1579327